# Прототипное наследование через класс не работает

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Должно появиться поле инпута, но оно не появляется. Где ошибка?

```js
'use strict';
  
  class Block{
    get name(){
      throw new Error('Invalid component name')
    }
    constructor(){
      this.el = document.createElement(this.name);
      
    }
    append(root){
      root.appendChild(this.el);
    }
  }
  
  window.Block = Block;
 
  class Input extends Block{
    get name(){
      return 'input';
    }
    constructor(placeholder){
      super();
      this.placeholder = placeholder;
    }
  }
  
  window.Input = Input;
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>

  <script>
    {
      'use strict';
      
      let input = new Input('Data');
      input.append(document.body);
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: "Где ошибка?" - хм, ошибка в консоли )

Comment: секция с кодом в сниппете вставляется перед закрывающим тегом body, поэтому код описанный в теге script в секции html, выполняется до того, как объявлены необходимые классы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Фрагмент кода" помещает код из окна "JavaScript" после кода из окна "HTML".

```js
'use strict';

class Block {
  get name() {
    throw new Error('Invalid component name')
  }
  constructor() {
    this.el = document.createElement(this.name);

  }
  append(root) {
    root.appendChild(this.el);
  }
}

window.Block = Block;

class Input extends Block {
  get name() {
    return 'input';
  }
  constructor(placeholder) {
    super();
    this.placeholder = placeholder;
  }
}

window.Input = Input;
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>

<script>
window.onload = () =>
{
    'use strict';

    let input = new Input('Data');
    input.append(document.body);
}
</script>
```